# Cannot Filter DataRows

Tags: vb.net, winforms, filter, datatable

I'm Using Following code to select Specific Rows From My Datatable But the problem is that it only searches full matching content from column

```
Dim strExpr = "`" + callerAHeader_Name + "` = " & iSrch & ""
Dim strSort = callerAHeader_Name + " DESC"
Dim foundRows As DataRow()

foundRows = ds.Tables(0).[Select](strExpr,strSort)
```

It Works Fine But To Search Matching Some Words I used

```
Dim strExpr = "`" + callerAHeader_Name + "` LIKE '%" & iSrch & "%'"
Dim strSort = callerAHeader_Name + " DESC"
Dim foundRows As DataRow()

foundRows = ds.Tables(0).[Select](strExpr,strSort)
```

Which Gives Me Error **"Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Double and System.String"**

If i remove inverted comma's from strExpr

```
Dim strExpr = "`" + callerAHeader_Name + "` LIKE %" & iSrch & "%"
```

it gives an error **Syntax error: Missing operand before 'Mod' operator.**

Comment: i guess the callerAHeader_Name variable is the name of a table column (field name) so instead of inverted commas you must use brackets [...] to escape their spaces. What is the data type of iSrch? is it an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Converting value of column at search time

```
Dim foundRows = ds.Tables(0).Select("Convert(" & callerAHeader_Name & ", 'System.String') LIKE '*" + TextBox1.Text + "*'")
```

Comment: Wooo Man You Rockss it Works Greatt . . . . . Thanks @Jadeja RJ

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Dim strExpr = "[" + callerAHeader_Name + "] LIKE '%" + Convert.ChangeType(iSrch, GetType(String)) + "%'"
Dim strSort = "[" + callerAHeader_Name + "] DESC"
```

EDIT: 
use GetType(String) instead of c# equivalent typeof(string)

you may also use & operator to concatenate string and integer values in vb but i prefer Convert.ChangeType